# C++ Mysql variable value changes when sent to database

Tags: mysql, database, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

I have a program where in a Text Box a user can type in names and gets suggested autocomplete otpions based on the rows stored in the 'player_name' coloumn of a MySQL database table named 'players'. When the user is happy with the name in the Text Box he would press a button "Choose" as a confirmation of his choice. Now I want to get the name in the text box and display additional information about the selected player (infos that are stored in another columns) in the same form.

Here is my code:

```
//AutoComplete Textbox

 void AutoCompleteTextbox()
 {
     PlayerNameField->AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode::SuggestAppend;
     PlayerNameField->AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource::CustomSource;
     AutoCompleteStringCollection ^PlayerSearchName = gcnew AutoCompleteStringCollection();
     String^ PlayerSearchAgeGroup;

     String^ constring = L"datasource=***.**.***.***;port=3306;username=AdminUser;password=****";
     MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
     MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand ("select * from mfs_manager_database.players;", conDataBase);
     MySqlDataReader^ myReader;


     try
     {
         conDataBase->Open();
         myReader = cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();


         while (myReader->Read())
         {

             searchName = myReader->GetString("player_name");
             PlayerID = myReader->GetString("player_id");
             String^ searchAgeGroup = myReader->GetString("player_age_group");
             PlayerSearchName->Add(searchName +" "+ searchAgeGroup);


        }

     }
     catch (Exception^ ex)
     {
         MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
     }

     PlayerNameField->AutoCompleteCustomSource = PlayerSearchName;
 }
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         //Disabling Player Name Field

         PlayerNameField->Enabled = false;

         //Getting Player Details for display from database


         String^ constring = L"datasource=***.**.***.***;port=3306;username=AdminUser;password=****";
         MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
         MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mfs_manager_database.players WHERE player_id = '"+PlayerID+"';", conDataBase);
         MySqlDataReader^ myReader;


         try
         {
             conDataBase->Open();
             myReader = cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();


             while (myReader->Read())
             {
                 String^ getName = myReader->GetString("player_name"); 
                 NameLabel->Text = getName;

             }

         }
         catch (Exception^ ex)
         {
             MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
         }
```

Everything works fine except that my I press the "Choose" button I get the ID of the last entry in the database not the selected player's.

Here is what I tried:

-I declared PlayerID and gave it a value '2' before the GetString, same result.

```
String^ PlayerID = "2";    
PlayerID = myReader->GetString("player_id");
```

-I gave PlayerID a value of "2" after the GetString, I get the name of the player occupying ID '2' (as expected)

```
PlayerID = myReader->GetString("player_id");
PlayerID = "2";
```

-I also checked if the GetString line working properly, I added the 'player_id' to the autocomplete suggestion and it shows the correct ID.

```
PlayerSearchName->Add(searchName +" "+ searchAgeGroup + PlayerID);
```

All of the components seem to work one by one but not all together and I can't see the reason why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the last player because in the constructor you are setting `PlayerID` to the last player in the database.  In your button click handler you are never updating that value and so when you run your query against the database you are always pulling back the record for the last `PlayerID` you set.

When this block of code is done executing `PlayerID` is the the last ID in the database:

```
while (myReader->Read())
{
     searchName = myReader->GetString("player_name");
     PlayerID = myReader->GetString("player_id");
     String^ searchAgeGroup = myReader->GetString("player_age_group");
     PlayerSearchName->Add(searchName +" "+ searchAgeGroup);
}
```

What you need to do is use the "Player name" that has been selected in the texbox and use that in the button click to search the database.

**Edit**
Based on your comments, here is a way in which you could accomplish this.  Change your loop where you build the auto complete list so that the string you put in the list looks like this.

```
String^ searchName = myReader->GetString("player_name");
String^ playerID = myReader->GetString("player_id");
String^ searchAgeGroup = myReader->GetString("player_age_group");
PlayerSearchName->Add(searchName +" "+ searchAgeGroup + "<" + searchName + ">");  // Note - it might be better to use String::Format here instead of concatenation
```

Then when you are going to look up the name, just pull the ID out of the text box string.

```
String^ name = autoCompleteBox->Text;
int index = name->LastIndexOf("<");
String^ id = name->Substring(index+1, name->Length - index);  // Double check this, I may be "off by one", I have not tested it
```

Now you should have the ID from the string and can use that to search.

You may also want to consider using a Dropdown control rather than auto complete.  Then you can add the ID to the control as the `Tag` for each item entry.  That way, when a name is chosen, you can just grab the selected item and pull the ID directly from the `Tag` field.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your answer. How could I update it properly? I am just learning this and sometimes having trouble so a bit help about the right direction for the 'updating' would be really helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you are saying was my original idea but I have two problems with it. First that there are duplicated names i nthe database with different ID's (different players with the same names) so I can't search based on their names the only unique thing they have is their ID. The second problem is that as you can see in the suggestion it shows their 'age_group' as well so I would have to delete the end of the string which is quite a headache I experimented with this solution as well but came to the conlusion that the best would be to use the PlayerID variable. Any idea how to go about this? Thanks

Comment: You have to maintain some kind of an association between the entries added to the autocomplete list and the player ids. I'm not really familiar with C++, so my suggestion would be to add the player ids to a list in exactly the same order as you add the names. If the user selects an option, then based on its index, you should be able to find which player id belongs to that entry.

Comment: First, let me thank you for your answer. I think I kinda see the problem now but what I still cannot understand is if the variables (searchName, searchAgeGroup, PlayerID) are "updating" in the Text Box when I type then why not in another place. I am really confused now. From my view what I see is if I put the PlayerID variable in a Text Box as autocomplete source it's working ( PlayerSearchName->Add(PlayerID);), but when I put it in a MySQL querry it's not. I am aware that the mistake is on my side but I just can't get to the right solution.

Comment: @MentalJewel - I have updated my answer to provide two alternatives for you.  One involving putting the ID in the autocomplete string and the other involving using a different control.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. First, answering to your Option 2, wouldn't that way the Dropdown list contain all the names in the database? If so, that wouldn't be an optimal choice since there are thousands of players in the database.
I tried your first suggestion though but now I'm having an unhandled exception error "OutOfRange". I did the following: I changed the while loop according to your suggestion, then inserted your code just before the "get the details" query, and then changed the variable in the query to "id". What am I doing wrong? Thank you again.

Comment: @pstrjds Thank you very much I got it working with your 'substring' solution! I had to change the code a bit to fit my needs, but you led me in the right direction, so thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

```
         while (myReader->Read())
     {

         searchName = myReader->GetString("player_name");
         PlayerID = myReader->GetString("player_id");
         String^ searchAgeGroup = myReader->GetString("player_age_group");
         PlayerSearchName->Add(searchName +" "+ searchAgeGroup);


    }
```

In the above loop you keep assigning the player id to the PlayerID variable, so its value will be those of the last entry in the database. I do not see the code anywhere adding the player ids to the list, I do not know from where your code should know which player was selected.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering. I am quite new to this and would appreciate a bit more help. I understand what you say, but then I don't see the reason why am I seeing the correct ID when I add PlayerID to the search suggestion, shouldn't it show the last id then as well? Why is it working there and not elsewhere? Could you please explain my mistake in more detail? Thank you in advance